# Apache qpid queue url

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, messaging, amqp

I'm trying to learn more information on how apache Qpid works and I do so by following examples from official svn :

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf

I was looking at :

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/trunk/qpid/java/client/example/src/main/java/org/apache/qpid/example/Hello.java

Which uses this configuration/property file :

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/trunk/qpid/java/client/example/src/main/java/org/apache/qpid/example/hello.properties

Can someone break down to me what this line from configuration represents :

```
connectionfactory.qpidConnectionfactory = amqp://guest:guest@clientid/test?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5672
```

i. I assume guest:guest would be the credentials which to use when connecting to the qpid

ii. I assume localhost and 5672 should be hostname:port

My question is what does `test?` represent ? is that a name of the queue or what is it? is it possible to specify queue name directly in this amqp url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: "test" stands for Qpid virtual host.

**Longer answer**: this whole HelloWord sample is explained [here](http://qpid.apache.org/books/0.7/Programming-In-Apache-Qpid/html/ch03.html), line-by-line. From that page, there is a link to [Apache Qpid JNDI Properties for AMQP Messaging](http://qpid.apache.org/books/0.7/Programming-In-Apache-Qpid/html/ch03s02.html) that explains the URL format:

> In JNDI properties, a Connection URL specifies properties for a connection. The format for a Connection URL is:

```
amqp://[<user>:<pass>@][<clientid>]<virtualhost>[?<option>='<value>'[&<option>='<value>']]
```

> For instance, the following Connection URL specifies a user name, a password, a client ID, a virtual host ("test"), a broker list with a single broker, and a TCP host with the host name “localhost” using port 5672:

```
amqp://username:password@clientid/test?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5672'
```

Virtual hosts are [configured](https://cwiki.apache.org/qpid/configure-the-virtual-hosts-via-virtualhostsxml.html) in virtualhosts.xml.

Comment: what if I send the message to non existing virtualhost will it be created dynamically ? +1

Comment: I do not have such experience, but I would guess not. But feel free to try it out! ;-)

Comment: qPid homepage has excellent resources and there are also some books available for free: http://qpid.apache.org/books/

Comment: the virtual host is not created dynamically.